# Can I create a visual studio 2008 starter kit that is based on a solution file with multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, starter-kits

I have successfully managed to create Visual Studio starter kits in the past, however as far as I am aware they can only be made at the project level.

I have a solution that contains multiple projects that I want to distribute throughout an organisation for several software projects.

The starter kit that I want to make is at the solution level, and contains multiple visual studio projects, that are clearly seperated, ( e.g. seperate code and test projects).

Does Visual Studio 2008 support this, and if so how is it done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364046(VS.80).aspx#creatstrtkt_topic3

Instead of deleteing this I thougt that it would be useful reference for someone else.